# centering a block with sub-menu items relative to the parent menu item

Tags: html, css, popup

I have a sidebar, with sub menu items. These subparagraphs are always displayed at the top of the departing block. Please tell me how to make the sub-menu items displayed in the center, relative to the height of their parent menu item from the sidebar. Like on a picture. Thank.

[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEtuh.png

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow > a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow:hover > a:after{
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="/content/video.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/content/rek.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Интернет</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Телевидение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using flexbox, you can add "justify-content: center;" to the parent of the sidebar (.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup) and that will vertically center your li's. Keep in mind that when the flex-direction is column, justify-content will affect the vertical alignment.

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow > a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow:hover > a:after{
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="/content/video.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/content/rek.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Интернет</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Телевидение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: based on comment

```js
var height = [100/7, 100/6, 100/5, 100/4, 100/3, 100/2, 100];
const submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup");
for (let i = 0; i<submenu.length; i++) {
  
  submenu[i].style.marginTop = height[i] + "vh";
  }
```

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
  top: -50px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup {
position: relative;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow > a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px;
  border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list > li.main_menu_content_list_arrow:hover > a:after{
  opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="" >
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="/content/video.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/content/rek.html">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li><div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a class="" href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <li class="main_menu_content_list_arrow"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Интернет</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Телевидение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right now the pop-up menu blocks are centered, but should be centered relative to their parent.

Comment: My apologies, I misread that, I see what you are looking for. I believe to achieve that you would have to do some calculations to see how far each parent link is from a set point, though I would have to fiddle with the code a bit to see. It is a bit late for me right now but if there is no answer, I will mess with it more in the morning.

Comment: Thanks you. I will wait for your reply.

Comment: You are probably very busy for my question ?! :-*(

Comment: Hi, very sorry! I have been a bit busy with a project. I am not completely sure how to solve this issue since the submenu links are not a direct child to the main menu links. Since the submenu container is position absolute and taken out of natural DOM flow, it is a bit harder to position its children relative to the main menu links. I tried to use key-value pairs to change the margin based on the index of element but it's not working. I included it in my post if you want to mess with it though. Sorry!

Comment: Hi. Don’t worry. I will try to solve my question myself. Thanks for the feedback.